# Clone a folder / raid on a folder?

Tags: linux, file, backup

I have two hard drive of 4Tb connected to my raspberry pi.
Let's call them A and B.

I have some folders on A that have to be copied on B. At all the time, something like a RAID10 on some folder. So, if I copy test.jpg in disk A, test.jpg has to be copied on disk B. If I copy test2.jpg on B, test2.jpg has to be copied on A.

So in case A or B crash, I still have an valid, up to date, copy of my files.

Is there anything that exist already ? Or should I use rsync and use it through service ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a solution. I'm using "rsnapshot" wich does exactly what I want.

https://rsnapshot.org/